# To find the limiting value of the function

Tags: calculus, limits

[The following image here. ][1]

*My answer came out to be 1 but doesn't seem so through graph *
What must be right? 1 or 0
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPDr7.jpg

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** When $h$ tends to $0$, $$\frac{\ln^2(1+h)\sin\left( \frac{1}{h}\right)}{h} \sim \frac{h^2\sin\left( \frac{1}{h}\right)}{h} = h \sin\left( \frac{1}{h}\right)$$
Now you can use a squeeze argument.

Comment: The answer would come out to be 1 then?

Comment: I used the fact that lim ln(1+x)/x =1. Liked your way too.

Comment: No. $h$ tends to $0$ and $\sin(1/h)$ is bounded, so the limit is......

Comment: Got it the limit is zero since sin is just oscillating thingy. Why my question shows -2 btw